# Create continuous intervals from overlapping ones

Tags: sql, hive, window-functions, impala

Let's say I have the following two tables `table1` and `table2`

```
CREATE TABLE lab_dlb_suba.table1 (id string, valid_from STRING, valid_to STRING);
INSERT INTO lab_dlb_suba.table1 VALUES
    ('ABC123', '2022-12-09', '2022-12-21'),
    ('ABC123', '2022-12-22', '2023-05-07'),
    ('ABC123', '2023-05-08', '9999-12-31')
    ;
```

```
CREATE TABLE lab_dlb_suba.table2 (id string, valid_from STRING, valid_to STRING);
INSERT INTO lab_dlb_suba.table2 VALUES
    ('ABC123', '2022-09-30', '  2022-12-30'),
    ('ABC123', '2022-12-31', '  2023-03-30')
    ;
```

I would like to create `dates` populated with continuous non-overlapping intervals from `table1` and `table2`

Below is what I have been using so far:

- Compute `Union` which is an union of all both tables twice to create a set of events with different type
- Compute `d2` using the lead() function
- Compute `dates` (final table) using lag() function

```
WITH `UNION` AS
(
       SELECT 1                   AS type,
              id                  AS id,
              to_date(valid_from) AS dt
       FROM   table1
       UNION ALL
       SELECT -1                AS type,
              id                AS id,
              to_date(valid_to) AS dt
       FROM   table1
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 1                   AS type,
              id                  AS id,
              to_date(valid_from) AS dt
       FROM   table2
       UNION ALL
       SELECT -1                AS type,
              id                AS id,
              to_date(valid_to) AS dt
       FROM   table2), 
`d2` AS
(
         SELECT   id,
                  type,
                  dt,
                  CASE
                           WHEN lead(type) OVER ( partition BY id ORDER BY dt ) = 1 THEN date_sub( lead(dt) OVER ( partition BY id ORDER BY dt ), 1 )
                           ELSE lead(dt) OVER ( partition BY id ORDER BY dt )
                  END AS d2
         FROM     `UNION` ), 
`dates` AS
(
         SELECT   id,
                  CASE
                           WHEN lag(d2) OVER ( partition BY id ORDER BY dt ) = dt THEN date_add(dt, 1)
                           ELSE to_date(dt)
                  END AS d1,
                  d2
         FROM     `d2`
         WHERE    (
                           type = 1
                  OR       d2 = '9999-12-31' ))
SELECT   *
FROM     `dates`
ORDER BY d1,
         d2
```

Which gives the following output

```
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
|   id   |         d1          |         d2          |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
| ABC123 | 2022-09-30 00:00:00 | 2022-12-08 00:00:00 |
| ABC123 | 2022-12-09 00:00:00 | 2022-12-21 00:00:00 |
| ABC123 | 2022-12-22 00:00:00 | 2022-12-30 00:00:00 |
| ABC123 | 2022-12-31 00:00:00 | 2023-03-30 00:00:00 |
| ABC123 | 2023-05-08 00:00:00 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00 |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

However, for this particular case, I am missing one interval

```
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
| ABC123 | 2023-03-31 00:00:00 | 2023-05-07 00:00:00 |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

And I don't know how to properly create it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I am using Impala, but the query should be Hive-friendly.
Please note this is a Minimal Reproducible Example and its intent is to be incorporated with 3 or 4 tables not only 2.

---

@PonderStibbons Added a third table and tried to adapt your query in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/T7cRTcNl). It creates overlaps.

Comment: Will [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/XVAuPkW4) Oracle solution help?

Comment: Hi - aren't you also missing a record starting at '2022-09-30'? Can you also update your question to confirm what the rules are, please? I assume order by valid_from and start with the smallest value; is the valid_from of the next record the valid_to of the previous record + 1, or is the valid_to of the previous record the valid_from of the next record - 1 ?

Comment: @PonderStibbons Thank you. Have tried to incorporate your solution with 3/4 tables now but it seems that there are overlaps. Can you please explain what is the `bx` source and how to accomodate to more tables than 2 ?

Comment: @NickW Hi. Thank you for spotting it, first missing interval was a copy/paste mistake. I edited the question. Not quite sure I understand your question very well. The idea is just to create continuous, non-overlapping validity ranges so I think it could be both.

Comment: 1) `bx` takes `valid_to + 1` from table2 as potential starting date of period. 2) more tables then two - similar, `cx` etc 3) can you edit your question and add some rows (or to my dbfiddle showing overlaps)?

Comment: @PonderStibbons Updated my question by adding some data in the dbfiddle example.

Comment: To try and clarify my question: say you have two record with start and end dates: 2023-01-01=>2023-01-20 and 2023-01-10=>2023-01-31. Do you want your result to be 2023-01-01=>2023-01-20 and 2023-01-21=>2023-01-31 (i.e. adjust the start date of the later record) or 2023-01-01=>2023-01-09 and 2023-01-10=>2023-01-31 (i.e. adjust the end date of the earlier record) ?

Comment: Query with third table: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/w9fo4cfV).

Comment: @NickW the former. I would like to adjust the start date of the later record

Comment: OK - but that's not what you are showing in your question. The first record (from both tables) is '2022-09-30' => ' 2022-12-30', so by the logic in your last comment the next record should have a valid_from of  '2022-12-31' - not the '2022-12-09' you have in your output. This also raises the question of what to do with this second record if its valid_from is now  '2022-12-31'  and it's valid_to is still '2022-12-21' i.e. its end is before its start?

Comment: @NickW I don't know how to put it in another way. I just want to create continuous non-overlapping intervals from non-continuous overlapping intervals. Therefore it is expected that the valid_to of the first record is 2022-12-08 00:00:00.

Comment: @PonderStibbons This works only if end of time (9999) is in table1, correct?

Comment: 9999 is added artificially, I assumed, that you want it always. If otherwise find max(end date) (for each ID) from all your tables and put it into inner union.

Comment: I’m just asking you to think through all the possible scenarios and define the rules for each scenario. We know which will be the first record based on the earliest from_date (I’ll assume we can’t have records with the same valid_from date - but that’s a scenario you may want to consider). The next record could have a valid_from before, the same or after the valid_to of the previous record - so for each of these scenarios how do we change the valid_from or valid_to of this second record? What happens if we change a date and this results in the from date being equal, or later, than the to date?